# Showing equivalence between definitions of a quadratic form

Tags: modules, quadratic-forms, multilinear-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring, and $M$ an $R$-module. One of the most useful ways of defining a quadratic form is as the diagonal of a bilinear form:

> *Definition 1*: A map $Q \colon M \to R$ is called a *quadratic form* if there exists some $R$-bilinear form $B \colon M \times M \to R$ such that $Q(m) = B(m, m)$ for all $m \in M$.

There is another more axiomatic definition, explicitly requiring that $Q$ behaves like a homogeneous polynomial of degree 2.

> *Definition 2*: A map $Q \colon M \to R$ is called a *quadratic form* if $Q(rm) = r^2 m$ for all $r \in R$ and $m \in M$, and the *polar form* $Q_P \colon M \times M \to R$ is a bilinear form, where $Q_P(m, n) = Q(m + n) - Q(m) - Q(n)$.

It is very easy to show that quadratic form in the sense of Definition 1 is a quadratic form in the sense of Definition 2, but I'm finding it difficult to show the converse.

> **Question:** Is there a simple proof that Definition 2 implies Definition 1 in general?

I can prove this with some further assumptions. The first easy case is if $2$ is invertible in $R$, since then we have that $\frac{1}{2} Q_P$ is a bilinear form such that $\frac{1}{2} Q_P(m, m) = Q(m)$.

The second easy case is if $M$ is free on some basis $\{e_i \mid i \in I\}$ where $I$ is totally ordered. (As far as I can tell, this covers basically every case that people actually use "in the real world"). We then define a bilinear form $B \colon M \times M \to R$ by setting
$$ B(e_i, e_j) = \begin{cases}
  Q_P(e_i, e_j) & \text{if } i < j, \\
  Q(e_i) & \text{if } i = j, \\
  0 & \text{if } i > j.
\end{cases}$$
Together with the fact that
$$ Q(m_1 + \cdots + m_n) = \sum_i Q(m_i) + \sum_{i < j} Q_P(m_i, m_j), $$
it is easily seen that $B$ is indeed a bilinear form on $M$ such that $B(m, m) = Q(m)$ for all $m \in M$.

Comment: I think they're actually not equivalent but I haven't been able to produce a counterexample. A sort of related fact is that not every symmetric bilinear form admits a quadratic refinement (a quadratic form whose polar form is the given bilinear form), but that's much easier.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't know if they're equivalent, hence the question. The related fact you mention I've always seen as an explicitly characteristic-two phenomenon: I understand it loosely as quadratic forms being elements of the symmetric power $S^2(M^*)$, with bilinear forms as elements of $M^* \otimes M^*$ and symmetric bilinear forms being the invariant tensors under the flip map $f \otimes g \mapsto g \otimes f$. Taking the diagonal of a bilinear form is the map to $S^2(M^*)$, and polarising is the symmetrising map $fg \mapsto f\otimes g + g \otimes f$, hence the characteristic-2 problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not equivalent. We'll say that $Q$ admits a *bilinear refinement* if there exists bilinear $B$ such that $Q(m) = B(m, m)$. Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/4$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}/2$, and consider the function $Q : M \to R$ given by

$$Q(0) = 0, Q(1) = 1.$$

We have $Q(rm) = r^2 Q(m)$ (this only imposes the condition that $Q(0) = 0$). The polar form, which I'll write $B_Q$, satisfies

$$B_Q(0, 0) = 0$$
$$B_Q(1, 0) = 0$$
$$B_Q(0, 1) = 0$$
$$B_Q(1, 1) = 2.$$

We can check that a map $B : M \times M \to R$ is bilinear iff $B(0, 0) = B(1, 0) = B(0, 1) = 0$ and $B(1, 1) \in 2 \mathbb{Z}/4$ (because the only nontrivial condition linearity imposes here is that $B(-1, 1) = B(1, -1) = -B(1, 1)$), which is the case here. So $Q$ is a quadratic form.

But $Q$ does not admit a bilinear refinement: any bilinear form $B$ must have image in $2 \mathbb{Z}/4$ and hence so must its diagonal quadratic form, which $Q$ doesn't.

The difference between these two definitions actually matters "in the real world," and the second definition turns out to be the correct one. For example, there is a cohomology operation called [Pontryagin square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_cohomology_operation) $H^{2k}(-, \mathbb{Z}/2) \to H^{4k}(-, \mathbb{Z}/4)$, which is quadratic. It's a lift of the cup square, to which it reduces $\bmod 2$, and I believe it does not admit a bilinear refinement, although I don't know enough about how to compute it to be sure.

For another example, given two abelian groups $\pi_2, \pi_3$ we can define a quadratic map $\pi_2 \to \pi_3$, which is a slight generalization of your second definition. If $\pi_2, \pi_3$ are the second and third homotopy groups of a space then there is a natural homotopy operation $\pi_2 \to \pi_3$ given by precomposing with the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration). This map is a quadratic refinement of the [Whitehead bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_product) $\pi_2 \times \pi_2 \to \pi_3$, and I believe it also does not admit a bilinear refinement. If $X$ is a space whose only nonvanishing homotopy groups are $\pi_2$ and $\pi_3$ then it is classified by a [$k$-invariant](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/k-invariant) $k \in H^4(B^2 \pi_2, \pi_3)$, and [it turns out](https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/barclect.pdf) that this cohomology group can naturally be identified with the group of quadratic maps $\pi_2 \to \pi_3$ (this is due to [Eilenberg and Mac Lane](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969702?seq=1)). In other words this homotopy operation completely classifies spaces whose only nonvanishing homotopy groups are $\pi_2, \pi_3$. Equivalently, it classifies braided monoidal grouplike groupoids (this is a mouthful but it's really a very natural thing to consider).

When $k = 1$ the Pontryagin square $H^2(-, \mathbb{Z}/2) \to H^4(-, \mathbb{Z}/4)$ is classified by a map $B^2 \mathbb{Z}/2 \to B^4 \mathbb{Z}/4$ and hence by a cohomology class in $H^4(B^2 \mathbb{Z}/2, \mathbb{Z}/4)$ which I would be willing to bet corresponds to the quadratic form $Q$ above, although I don't know how to prove this.

For more of this sort of thing see, for example, Hopkins and Singer's *[Quadratic functions in geometry, topology, and M-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211216)*.

Comment: @Joppy: whoops, you're right. Fortunately I just miscalculated and we do have $B(0, 1) = B(1, 0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks - it took me a bit to see why $B(1, 1)$ was necessarily in $2 \mathbb{Z} / 4$ (because $2 \cdot B(1, 1) = 0$ by bilinearity, hence $B(1, 1) \in \mathbb{Z} / 4$ needs to be killed by $2$). Your answer raises the question: what does it mean to be a quadratic (or cubic, etc) map $M \to N$ between modules over a commutative ring $R$? I'm thinking here of a third definition of quadratic form on a vector space: a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2$ in some coordinate functions. But I can't see a good way to generalise that, and your answer shows that there could be some surprises.

Comment: @Joppy: it's a map $Q : M \to N$ such that $Q(rm) = r^2 Q(m)$ and such that the polar form $B_Q(m, n) = Q(m + n) - Q(m) - Q(n)$ is bilinear, same as Definition 2, except that $B_Q$ is now a map $M \times M \to N$. I seem to recall that there's an analogous definition for a cubic map etc. but I don't remember the precise form of it. A guess is that a cubic map is a map such that $C(rm) = r^3 C(m)$ and such that $C(m + n + k) - C(m + n) - C(n + k) - C(k + m) + C(m) + C(n) + C(k)$ is quadratic.